# Find Inverse Laplace Transform

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform

I'm trying to calculate

$$L_s^{-1}\left({\cfrac{2s+12}{s^2+9}}\right)=2L_s^{-1}\left({\cfrac{s+6}{s^2+9}}\right)$$

But I do not know how to go from here. I have noticed that the bottom does look like it is in the form of $L({cos(wt))}$ where w=3 but I do not know where to go from here.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\cfrac{2s+12}{s^2+9}=2\cfrac{s}{s^2+3^2}+\cfrac{12}{3}\cfrac{3}{s^2+3^2}$$
[Here](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Laplace_Table.aspx) a good table for Laplace transform (note the inverse transform is linear)

Solution

> $2\cos(3t)+4\sin(3t)$

Comment: @Silynn, Thanks for your comment